# Unable to determine current character, it is not a string, number, array or object?

Tags: json, groovy

Please help with the Groovy script. I am using this groovy script in apache nifi but all the inputs are Json actually and not string or Object. And I think thats why I am getting error.

I want to know how can I use json or convert json into String or object so that my code can work.
The code:

**FlowFile Content **

```
"COVID-19"
```

The Response has data like this

```
Response
{
  "Name" : {
    "COVID-19" : [ "88" ],
    "Fever" : [ "40" ]
}
}
```

I want to access 88 in data1 finally  and send it to ahead after execute script.

In s3data, there is varibale named SID which has same as of COVID-19, so I want to match it with flowfile content and whichever flowfile content will match it will send its id i.i 88 in this example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resolve Script Exception in groovy in apache nifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76145826/how-to-resolve-script-exception-in-groovy-in-apache-nifi)

Comment: what script:????

Comment: @injecteer I have updated alot in my question can you please help a look on the question again.

Comment: which line is throwing the Exception?

Comment: I tried by adding double quotes on flowfile content now  I am getting new error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155966/expecting-current-character-to-be-with-an-int-value-of-34-the-current-charact  .... This is the new erro

Comment: let's go step by step...

Comment: @injecteer Can you please have a look on this question, I'll be really thankful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155966/how-to-write-groovy-script-for-apache-nifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to parse the JSON from text and find the desired value can look like so:

```
import groovy.json.*

String nameToFind = 'COVID-19'

String VRResponseText = '''{ "customReasonName" : { "COVID-19" : [ "88" ], "Fever" : [ "40" ] } }'''

def VRResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText VRResponseText

String desiredValue = VRResponse.customReasonName.findResult{ k, v -> k == nameToFind ? v[ 0 ] : null }

assert desiredValue == '88'
```

Comment: I cant add theses values manually I have everything in flowfile and very dynamic data

Comment: you define the `nameToFind` variable to be smth like `S3data.SID.toString()`

Comment: what is assert desiredValue?

Comment: And in desiredValue there will be id 40 in your case right?

Comment: assert is for testing, like `if( a == b )`, it's value is `'88'`

Comment: So now after trying your way also I am on the same error as I mentioned earlier this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155966/expecting-current-character-to-be-with-an-int-value-of-34-the-current-charact